# Running multiple SQL create table scripts and \copy commands in an order, while also setting the Schema in psql?

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

I have a folder with both SQL files and CSV files, which I am using to populate the tables created from the SQL files.

For example, the folder may look like this:

> table_1.sql
>
> data_1.csv
>
> table_2.sql
>
> data_2.csv

For the above, I would like to run the CREATE TABLE sql script, import the csv into that table (at the moment I am doing this with \copy) and then continue with the 2nd table and csv in the same way.

The \copy command I'm currently using looks like:

> \copy schema_name.table_name (field1,field2,field2) FROM 'data_1.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER QUOTE '"' ESCAPE '''';

I would like to set the order in which this is run, but also set the schema these are execute within.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Create a *master* sql file, which does `SET search_path=newschema;` and then includes (`\i`) all the .sql files in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. I'm guessing I can just do the same for the imports, but instead of \i I would use \copy etc etc?